# Using iCloud Local Drive for Installation

Tags: installation, macbook, storage, icloud, external-drive

Is there a way that you can use the iCloud space on the hard drive for an installation?  I am installing programming which is asking me for space it only needs temporarily.  Ia there a way I can use this space then restore the content? I am installing new content to an external drive but it's still asking me for more space on my hard drive.  Bonus points: How does this temporary borrowing of space work?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you are using iCloud to save space on your local drive, then as the drive gets too full, least-used data & apps are pushed to the cloud to free up space on your local drive. You don't get to choose specifically which data is moved this way.

Any time you need that data, it has to be pulled back from the cloud before you can use it.

This means it is not a viable option to create more space from 'thin air'.
iCloud's predominant use-case is as a constant sync between devices, rather than as actual independent storage.
Best is if you just don't keep your drive so full that it's constantly starved for space. We live in [or hopefully towards the end of] an era where SSD storage was expensive, so millions of people own laptops with fixed, non-swappable SSDs that are really far too small. iCloud's space management is an attempt to mitigate that, but really nothing can substitute for actual space on your drive.

If you look at Disk Utility with your boot volume selected, the figure in the table for "Available:" shows a figure for purgeable data. This is the data that can be shuffled aside if space is needed - but it won't do it all at once if an app suddenly requests it.
The figure under the thermometer scale above, marked "Free" is the amount of space you have available for a sudden request.
The figure in About this Mac/Storage, also fails to take account of purgeable data, so only the "Free" figure in Disk Utility is reliable.

[image]